# How can I make an image appear in the center of the Header?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

Firstly, my code is based on 3 files, an HTML, a CSS and a JS, it should be noted that I am creating the HTML with the Bootstrap 5.1.3 framework.

My problem is that first, the logo of the clothing brand that I have as a case study is not centered and I have tried everything to make it centered in the Header, however, it has not been possible for me to achieve it. I also add that I have a drop-down search engine, that is, I press the search icon and it shows me a box on the right for a text input, well, when that happens and said box appears, the logo, in addition to not being centered, it rolls more to the left (because I have the search on the right) and I don't know what exactly happens.

I know that it is most likely due to the containers, but I have also tried to reduce the logo container and center it, however, nothing has resulted, it remains exactly the same. I wish you could help me. I'm trying to study the framework but this, this little detail, doesn't let me move forward.

```js
// selecciona el icono de búsqueda y el campo de búsqueda
const searchIcon = document.querySelector('.fa-search-icon');
const searchField = document.querySelector('.search-container input[type="text"]');

// agrega un event listener al icono de búsqueda
searchIcon.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // muestra u oculta el campo de búsqueda
  searchField.style.display = searchField.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  height: 72px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-link {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* Estilos para los enlaces del header */

.navbar-nav li a {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Estilos para el logo */

.navbar-brand {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Estilos para la imagen del logo */

.navbar-brand img {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
}

.navbar-center {
  max-width: 300px;
  /* ajustar el ancho máximo según tus necesidades */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* centrar horizontalmente */
}


/* Estilos para el botón de hamburguesa en dispositivos móviles */

.navbar-toggler {
  border-color: #333;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-color: #333;
}


/* Estilos para los enlaces Contact Us y Cart en pantallas pequeñas */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /* Estilos para la barra de búsqueda en pantallas pequeñas */
  .navbar-form {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: none;
  }
  .navbar-form .form-control {
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: #333;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .navbar-form .input-group-text {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .navbar-form .input-group-text:hover,
  .navbar-form .input-group-text:focus {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
  }
}


/* Animación para desplazar el ícono a la izquierda */

.search-container input[type="text"] {
  display: none;
}

.search-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Men</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Women</a></li>
        </ul>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" style="max-width: 146px;">
        </a>

        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item search-container">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar...">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-search fa-search-icon"></i></a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-open"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

1. I tried centering the logo normally
2. I tried reducing the container of the logo
3. I tried redoing the code from 0

I have tried that several times and more to change the css so that the logo is centered, or decrease the container of the logo, but still I have not achieved anything, the logo always stayed in the same part.

And when I did it, yes, I also managed to center the logo, it turns out that the contain overlapped the Header, thus making it impossible to select any section of the Header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you should try to remove `width: 100%;` from the `.navbar-brand`.

You should also add this code :

```
.navbar-nav {
  flex: 1;
}
```

to make all navigations links centered, but be careful, because all elements will take the remaining space between them, and this code:

```
.navbar-collapse {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

to prevent the logo from moving when the search input appears.